# Android: Creating file using createNewFile() method

Tags: android

As described in android documentation, to create a new file which will be situated in the application's directory there is the method in `Context` class: `openFileOutput()`.

But where will be the file situated if I use simple `createNewFile()` method from `File` class.?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

CreateNewFile() is used like this:

```
File file = new File("data/data/your package name/test.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

So you will tell the file where it should be created. Remember that you can only create new files on your package. That is "data/data/your package name/".

Answer (score 4):

Somehow `createNewFile()` was not able to create the complete file path here on my devices.

```
try {
    if (!futurePhotoFile.exists()) {
        new File(futurePhotoFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
        futurePhotoFile.createNewFile();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("", "Could not create file.", e);
    Crouton.showText(TaskDetailsActivity.this,
            R.string.msgErrorNoSdCardAvailable, Style.ALERT);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be stored in the current directory to which your `classPath` is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the path you pass to the File constructor. If the parent directory exists, and if you have the permission to write to it, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of `createNewFile()` method says:

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.

Therefore we don't need to check existence of a file manually:

```
val dir = context.filesDir.absolutePath + "/someFolder/"
val logFile = File(dir + "log.txt")
try {
    File(dir).mkdirs()     // make sure to call mkdirs() when creating new directory
    logFile.createNewFile()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```