# Android File Doesn't Exist (But does at the same time!)

Tags: java, android, file

I have an Android program that creates a file and checks for it in an if statement. The purpose of this is to be able to save values in the app. The app works like this. I put the values in on the phone and I crash the app to reset it. The values were saved on the file. When I open the app again, it's supposed to skip the screen that lets me input the values. When I do this, the app acts as if the file never existed. Upon debug, I found that the file was indeed created. It should've been created on internal storage, but I also added the permission for external storage writing just in case. Can someone help me or give me an alternative please?

```
File file = new File("user.txt");
    if (file.exists())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a SQLite databse to save data?

Comment: Use `SharedPreference` if you don't have very large no of `DATA` to save.

Comment: Which directory are you saving the files to? Just as shown above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Creating file using createNewFile() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011991/android-creating-file-using-createnewfile-method)

Answer (score 0):

try to give it a full path  not only the file name, like this

```
File mFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
```

Comment: Like `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mysdfile.txt");` yes.

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder is read only at runtime.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

> Tip: If you want to save a static file in your application at compile time, save the file in your project res/raw/ directory. You can open it with openRawResource(), passing the R.raw. resource ID. This method returns an InputStream that you can use to read the file (but you cannot write to the original file).

Take a look at using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for saving primitive data types.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

                File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/Filename");
                if (!direct.exists()) {
                    direct.mkdir(); // directory is created;
                }
                if (isSDPresent) {
                    Path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/Filename";

                } else {
                    Path = getFilesDir() + "/Folder/Filename";
                }
        File f = new File(Path);
      if(!file.exists()) {
       try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```