# Android Subfolder sdcard

Tags: android

I create a folder called "res" inside sdcard

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/res/");
f.mkdirs();
```

The folder is successfully created.

But when I try to create a file within the folder does not work.

```
String string = "hello!";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/res/","test.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

LOGCAT

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/res/test.txt (Not a directory)
```

Comment: Just call `file.createNewFile();` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `new File()` doesn't actually create the file. You need to check if the file exists by using `file.exists()`. If it doesn't, you must create the file by calling `file.createNewFile()`. See this answer for sample code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7012122/379245